# A regexp that includes all combinations of numbers, dots and commas, but excludes records consisting of a single comma only

Tags: regex

> `^[\d,.]+$`

The above regexp will choose all combinations of numbers, dots and commas. However, I need it not to return the records consisting of a single comma only.

How to adjust it?

I'm trying to find all numerical segments in my translation project in Trados, then find-and-replace all Russian-style decimal commas with decimal points. However, some translation segments in the document consist of a comma only: the parser is not very precise in Trados. I need not to change those commas into dots by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!,$)[\d,.]+$
```

where

`(?!,$)` is a negative lookahead, a zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have a comma alone in the input string.

Comment: Would it not exclude records like `,302`, where comma is at the beginning but is followed by some number?

Comment: @CopperKettle: No, it wouldn't because of the `$` inside the lookahead, it means not a comma between begining and end of line (ie. a single comma).

Comment: [Indeed - I checked it!](https://regex101.com/r/v5K0Pp/2) Thank you!